# logstash grok filter for logs with arbitrary attribute-value pairs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

(This is related to my other question [logstash grok filter for custom logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884094/logstash-grok-filter-for-custom-logs) )

I have a logfile whose lines look something like:

```
14:46:16.603 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  METERING - msg=93e6dd5e-c009-46b3-b9eb-f753ee3b889a CREATE_JOB job=a820018e-7ad7-481a-97b0-bd705c3280ad data=71b1652e-16c8-4b33-9a57-f5fcb3d5de92
14:46:17.378 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] INFO  METERING - msg=c1ddb068-e6a2-450a-9f8b-7cbc1dbc222a SET_STATUS job=a820018e-7ad7-481a-97b0-bd705c3280ad status=ACTIVE final=false
```

I built a pattern that matched the first line:

```
%{TIME:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:http} %{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{WORD:logtype} - msg=%{NOTSPACE:msg}%{SPACE}%{WORD:action}%{SPACE}job=%{NOTSPACE:job}%{SPACE}data=%{NOTSPACE:data}
```

but obviously that only works for lines that have the `data=` at the end, versus the `status=` and `final=` at the end of the second line, or other attribute-value pairs on other lines?  How can I set up a pattern that says that after a certain point there will be an arbitrary of `foo=bar` pairs that I want to recognize and output as attribute/value pairs in the output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change your grok pattern like this to have all the key value pairs in one field (`kvpairs`):

```
%{TIME:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:http} %{WORD:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{WORD:logtype} - %{GREEDYDATA:kvpairs}
```

Afterwards you can use the [kv filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) to parse the key value pairs.

```
kv {
    source => "kvpairs"
    remove_field => [ "kvpairs" ] # Delete the field afterwards
}
```

Unfortunately, you have some simple values inside your kv pairs (e.g. `CREATE_JOB`). You could parse them with grok and use one kv filter for the values before and another kv filter for the values after those simple values.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need -- one question, can I suppress the output of the entire kvpairs value in my output?