# Change nginx access log data in logstash or elasticsearch

Tags: nginx, elasticsearch, logstash

In my project I provide api for a mobile app , and in every api the front end use `session_id` to mark user authenticity, and in the server side accept and validate it.

Recently we want to use ELK(`elasticsearch`, `logstash`, `kibana`) to preserve and analyze web server access log  to extract some  commonly occurred user activities. I encountered some problems, I wanna change `session_id` in the log to `user_id`(in program I can get `user_id` from `session_id` through query database) but I just don't know how?

Can `logstash's` filter do this? or should I change data when log was indexed in `elasticsearch`?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't have a `user_id` field in your logs and you want to add one? Do you have some kind of api from which you can retrieve the `user_id` (e.g. a rest api)?

Comment: the log lines is something like this `POST /wiki/wiki_list?session_id=032ce12841c7d0378be12f18f8e030f404a91c76&tag_id=1280 HTTP/1.1`
In program I retrieve `session_id` from post fields and use this to find the corresponding `user_id`

Comment: Okay, and is it possible to do that outside the program? I.e. is there an  api which receives the `session_id` and sends back the `user_id`? You will need an interface from which you can gather the `user_id` information.

Comment: It's now have a common function in my program to get corresponding `user_id` , anyway  I can write a separate interface to do this outside the program.

Comment: Suppose that you write an api which converts your `session_id` into a `user_id` (e.g. via http post) you could use a logstash filter which calls this api automatically and adds your `user_id` to each event. Let me know if you need help with the filter. But first, you need to set up your converting function to be externally available.

Comment: Yeah a filter to convert `session_id` into `user_id` is what I really want to express about my confusion. Cause I'm very new on `logstash` so I really need some help to figure out how to use `logstash` filter to convert this. Thanks to mush for your analyses about my question . Could you give some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I try to give you an answer assuming that you have some kind of interface from which you can retrieve the `user_id`. Actually you need to do two things:

1. Split your log line into separate fields to have a field which contains your `session_id`
2. Get the corresponding `user_id` using some kind of api

**Split your log line**

You need to split your input into separate fields. This could be done with filters like [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) and/or [kv](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html). Take a look at [some SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884204/logstash-grok-filter-for-logs-with-arbitrary-attribute-value-pairs/31884354#31884354) to find a matching grok pattern or use the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). Please provide a few log lines if you need help with that.

**EDIT:** For your given examples your configuration should look something like this:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ 'message', '"%{WORD:verb} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) (?:"(?:%{URI:referrer}|-)"|%{QS:referrer}) %{QS:agent} %{QS:xforwardedfor}' ]
    }
    kv {
        field_split => "&?"
    } 
}
```

Please try it and adjust it yourself to get the `session_id`.

Once you have a field called `session_id` you can go on with step 2.

**Get the user_id**

As you have already mentioned you need a filter plugin because the `session_id` must be available. There are several [official plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) but I think none of them suits your purpose. Since the `session_id` is assigned dynamically you cannot use a static [translate filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) or something like that.

It depends on your api but one possible approach is to get the corresponding `user_id` via http requests. For that purpose you could use a community plugin. For example [logstash-filter-rest](https://rubygems.org/gems/logstash-filter-rest) with a config like this:

```
filter {
    rest {
        url => "http://yourserver/getUserBySessionId/"
        sprintf => true
        method => "post"
        params => {                      
            "session_id" => "%{session_id}"        
        }
        response_key => "user_id"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights and warmly help,  the log lines are like below:
`"POST /memo_set/create?course_id=15&native_set_id=1439437893&set_name=%E6%97%A5%E5%B8%B8%E6%98%93%E9%94%99100%E5%AD%97%EF%BC%88%E6%89%BE%E9%94%99%E5%AD%97%EF%BC%89&create_time=1439437893&last_edit_time=1439437893&session_id=2647fc9fb9fe9c569019775904aca835e45daa7f HTTP/1.1" 200 129 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; vivo X5Pro D Build/LRX21M)" "-"`

Comment: See my edit. Should be a good start. But please try to figure out further steps yourself. It is not that complicated ;)

Comment: Yeah, I will consult you if I have confusion when  using that community plugin you recommended above . Thank you for your warmly help agin, have a good day ：-）

Comment: Hi hurb, do you have any time? I had a problem on logstash-filter-rest, and you can see my description on this question page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250615/logstash-filter-rest-sent-field-references-incorrectly-it-always-reference-first)