# Logstash-filter-rest sent field references incorrectly it always reference first field value it had referened

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I recently use [logstash-filter-rest](https://github.com/lucashenning/logstash-filter-rest), and configure it like below:

```
rest {
    url => "http://example.com/api"
    sprintf => true
    method => "post"
    params => {
      "post_key" => "%{a_field_in_log}"
    }
    response_key => "my_key"
}
```

after this, logstash make a post request to my api, but something is wrong, the value of  `a_field_in_log`
is identical in every request ( I check api access log, all of the value is the first field value sent to api ) it seems like there have caches for referenced field.

Does someone had encountered same problem, would thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, I'm the author of [logstash-filter-rest](https://github.com/lucashenning/logstash-filter-rest) and I'm glad to hear that someone is actually using it.

I was able to reproduce your issue. It was a bug and (good news) I fixed it. Thank you for reporting!

You can update now to the **new version 0.1.5**.

```
../logstash/bin/plugin update logstash-filter-rest
```

**Test config:**

```
input { stdin {} }
filter {
        grok { match => [ "message",  "Hello %{WORD:who}" ] }
        rest {
                url => "http://requestb.in/1f7s1sg1?test=%{who}"
                method => "post"
                sprintf => true
                params => {
                        "hello" => "%{who}"
                }
        }
}
output { stdout{ codec => "rubydebug" } }
```

**Test data:**

```
Hello John
Hello Doe
Hello foo
Hello bar
```

**Result:**

http://requestb.in/1f7s1sg1?inspect (looks good)

Many thanks for contributing! I hope everything works as expected now.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your response, I will update it tomorrow and inform you the result.

Comment: Hi, I updated new version, and the problem I mentioned has solved but not very well, it send %{file_name} literally (not value )to api from time to time .

Comment: Oh, too bad. Thank you for reporting. I'll try to reproduce that bug and get back to you soon.